# Google App Engine Entity Ownership

Tags: google-app-engine

I am writing an app for GAE in Python which stores recipes for different users. I have an entity called User in the datastore and an entity called Recipe. I want to be able to set the owner of each Recipe to the User who created it. Also, I want each User entity to contain a list of all Recipes belonging to that User as well as being able to query the Recipe database to find all Recipes owned by a particular User.

What is the best way to go about creating this parent/child type relationship?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There are two main ways.  (I am going to assume your using python which defines examples)

Option 1. Make the User the ancestor of all of their recipes

```
recipe = Recipe(parent=user.key)
```

Option 2.  Use key property

```
class Recipe(ndb.Model):
    owner = ndb.KeyProperty()

recipe = Recipe(owner=user.key)
```

all recipes for user with option 1

```
recipes = Recipe.query(ancestor=user.key)
```

all recupes for user with option 2

```
recipes = Recipe.query().filter(Recipe.owner == user.key)
```

Which one you use really depends a lot on what you plan to do with the data after creation, transaction patterns etc....  You should elaborate on your use cases.  Both will work.

Also you should read up on transactions entity groups and understand them to really determine if you want to use ancestors https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/transactions?hl=en .

Answer (score 1):

If you use db.Model, to model one-to-many relationship, you can use the `RefernenceProperty` constructor and specify a `collection_name`. For example, one book may have many reviews.

```
    class Book(db.Model):
    title = db.StringProperty()
    author = db.StringProperty()

    class BookReview(db.Model):
        book = db.ReferenceProperty(Book, collection_name='reviews')

    b = Book() 
    b.put()
    br = BookReview()  
    br.book = b # sets br's 'book' property to b's key 

    for review in b.reviews:# use collection_name to retrieve all reviews for a book
        ....
```

see https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/datamodeling#references

Alternatively, you can use ndb's `KeyProperty` as in Tim's answer.

Also see
[db.ReferenceProperty() vs ndb.KeyProperty in App Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16807108/db-referenceproperty-vs-ndb-keyproperty-in-app-engine)